# How to decompress lz4 file in crontab

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, lz4

I set a crontab to execute a shell script periodically.

Here is part of my shell script:

```
lz4 -d 'filename.json.lz4'
```

The shell script does work when I run it directly through the command line, and it will decompress the lz4 file to a json file.

However, when the script is executed by crontab, it does not decompress to a json file. Instead, it put all the data into the log file.

Here is my crontab:

```
25 23 3 * * sh /home/work/file.sh >> /home/work/log.txt 2>&1
```

I've tried the following ways but no one works:

```
echo `lz4 -d 'filename.json.lz4'` > 'filename.json' #put the result into a json file

25 23 3 * * sh /home/work/file.sh #change the crontab

subprocess.call(["lz4", "-d", "filename.json.lz4"]) #call lz4 function in python script
```

I guess there might be something weird when using lz4 in crontab. But I don't know how to deal with this problem. Hope someone could help me, thanks in advance!